# Why am I seeing the "cannot find symbol error" in java when creating an object from another class?

Tags: java, object, oop, methods, cannot-find-symbol

This is my primary class named Revenue where I'm trying to call a secondary class in same directory as this one and in the same package as well

```
package Hotel;

//import java.util.*;

public class Revenue {
    String Name;
    
    Revenue()
    {
        Name="";
    }
    public void Guest() 
    {
        
        System.out.println("Revenue Guest. ");
        Persons x = new Persons(); //Here's where the error is actually occuring
        System.out.println("Guest name:" + x.name() );  
        
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        System.out.println("Revenue main.");
        Revenue rev = new Revenue();
        rev.Guest();
    }
}
```

Now the next part is secondary class

```
package Hotel;

public class Persons {
    String firstName[] = {"Adam","Alex", "Steve", "Sira"};
 
    public Persons()
    {

    }
    public String name() {
        System.out.println("Persons name");
        java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
        String name = firstName[r.nextInt(firstName.length)];
        return name; 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Persons n = new Persons();
        System.out.println(n.name());
    }
}//class
```

And yes it works fine on debug mode through vs code (Redhat java something). But when i try to do javac Revenue.java or java Revenue.java in cmd it shows an error like this.

```
Revenue.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        Persons x = new Persons();
        ^
  symbol:   class Persons
  location: class Revenue
Revenue.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        Persons x = new Persons();
                        ^
  symbol:   class Persons
  location: class Revenue
2 errors
error: compilation failed
```

It's been whole 24 hours but I'm not able to figure it out what's the issue here :(

I tried creating a program named revenue that will extract a persons name from another class named person(Just for the sake of future expansion of person class). And in BlueJ it seemed to work pretty fine without any error but recently I switched to cmd and vs code and here I'm stuck with this code where it wont let me call a method from another class.

Comment: go to the parent of the "hotel" folder. Then `javac hotel/Revenue.java'

Comment: The Java compiler uses classes' fully-qualified names to find them or their sources.  The package name maps to a directory tree, and the class name to a filename.  To compile from the command line, make sure that the directory containing your two sources is named `Hotel`, and *from its parent directory*, run `javac Hotel/Revenue.java`.

Comment: I tried this method and then tried java Hotel/Revenue.class and java Revenue.class (going into hotel directory). Both showed an error java .\Revenue.class
Error: Could not find or load main class .\Revenue.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /\Revenue/class

Comment: Having successfully compiled, you *run* it via its fully-qualified **class** name.  Supposing you're still in the same directory from which you compiled, the command would be `java Hotel.Revenue`.

Comment: *Tangential: If `Persons` represents a single person (which it appears to) it should be named `Person` (singular) to avoid confusion.*

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. Somehow John this java Hotel.Revenue thing worked and it's working perfectly fine! Thanks for the help. Although it's still a little confusing to me how it's making a difference

Comment: Yeah. I felt that Persons should be renamed but just for the sake of not getting an error due to any misspelt word, I avoided that risk.

Comment: And the `Hotel` package should be named `hotel` ... to conform with Java style rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try the command `java className.java` to compile and execute like `java Persons.java`. It should work.

[image]